# mpd тихий звук OrangePi

Tags: linux, debian, arm, alsa

Добрый день.
Есть устройство: OrangePi PC H3
ОС: Armbian

Не могу увеличить громкость проигрывания музыки через mpd

```
user@orangepipc:~$ mpc status
Ultra FM: Buzzhorn - Ordinary
[playing] #1/1   7:56/0:00 (0%)
volume:100%   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off
```

при этом, в наушниках практически ничего не слышно, (условно, громкость на уровне 1-5%)
Но, при воспроизведении через aplay, громкость нормальная.

```
root@orangepipc:/home/user# aplay /root/piano2.wav 
Playing WAVE '/root/piano2.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Stereo
```

В настройках alsamixer все параметры выставлены на максимум,
конфиг mpd:

```
audio_output {
    type            "alsa"
    name            "My ALSA Device"
    device          "hw:0,0"        # optional
    mixer_type      "software"      # optional
#       mixer_device    "default"       # optional
#       mixer_control   "PCM"           # optional
#       mixer_index     "0"             # optional
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как принудительно увеличить громкость на устройстве?

UPD: громкость воспроизведения все-же зависит почему-то от формата потока\файла.
так, например mp3 звучит тихо, wav - на отличной громкости.
Одни радиостанции тихо, другие - громко.

Вопрос немного видоизменяется: как настроить одинаковую громкость на всех потоках\файлах?

Comment: Попробуйте закомментировать строку с mixer_type. Тогда mpd будет сам управлять громкостью устройства alsa.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но никаких изменений не произошло. software, hardware, без параметра, никакой разницы.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечаю на свой же вопрос:

банально, но RTFM!
в конфиге MPD есть опция:

volume_normalization

она то и должна иметь значение "yes"

после пересборки последней версии, 
включения вышеупомянутой опции, вопрос решился. на всех потоках уровень громкости одинаков.

всем спасибо!